# How do I mount a folder from another partition?

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, directory, partitioning

Is there a command to mount a folder from one partition to my main partition?

Example of what I'd like to do, which obviously doesn't work:

`mount /media/tc1/folder /home/dvad/home`

If not by using a command, is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Yes but before I go that far, couldn't you just symlink?

```
ln -s /media/tc1/folder ~/home
```

This link is just a file that is interpreted. It is automatically permanent (until you delete the file).

Failing that you can use `mount` as you described but the syntax is slightly different:

```
mount --bind /media/tc1/folder /home/dvad/home
```

This is not permanent at all, and will be nuked by a restart. If you want it to persist, you'll need something in your `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
/media/tc1/folder    /home/dvad/home    none    bind
```

If you're trying a mount and it's not working, you should make sure that the block-level device is mounted. You can't directly mount a subdirectory of a partition without first mounting the partition.

Comment: Thanks for the fstab trick. I use `mount --bind` to "link" folders into a users home folder that I expose to my friends (symlink doesn't play well with chroot) and now I don't have to re-do it or run a script that does it after each reboot. Not sure why I didn't think of using fstab before as I use it for all my media drives. Thanks again!

Comment: mount --bind source destination

Comment: `mount --bind` is useful in chroot'ed environment - since symlinks doesn't work there.

Comment: I'm trying a mount and it's not working, and I made sure the partition is mounted. What might be going on?

Comment: @Marc.2377 Ensure the folder you want to mount to exists and that you have chmod'd that folder.

Comment: Just adding a note- this is a good alternative to the more complex Apache directory ALIAS and often solves Forbidden issues in a safer way. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the fstab entry be `/media/tc1/folder    /home/dvad/home    none    bind 0 0` instead? Isn't the `0 0` at the end required?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Nope. `man fstab` will tell you the final two fields  `Defaults to zero (don't {dump,fsck}) if not present.`

Comment: Symlinks also don't work in webdav, where `mount --bind` does.

Comment: I wanted another user to have access to a folder inside my partition but not the partition itself. So I mounted that folder inside `/media/<another user name>/folder` using `mount --bind`. I guess you can't do this with symlink (I didn't try).

Comment: This is very good use also for snap as I have homedir elsewhere than /home/user

Answer (score 18):

An alternative to `mount`:

```
bindfs --no-allow-other /media/tc1/folder /home/dvad/home
```

May require `sudo apt install bindfs`.

Like with `mount`, this will be a (non-permanent) actual mount point. That means for instance version-control systems will not track it as a mere symbolic reference, but see the files “in there” as if they were lying on the single partition. Meanwhile, like for `ln -s`, you do not need superuser permissions for `bindfs` as you would for `mount`.

Unmount with `fusermount -u /home/dvad/home` (or by restarting).