# Mount HDD to a new location

Tags: partitioning, mount, unmount

My SSD(`sdb`) in mounted on `/` and HDD(`sda`) on `/home`. I want to unmount my HDD from `/home` and mount it on `/home/naufil/Desktop`. Please let me know step by step. I don't want my ubuntu to crash

Comment: You may not fully understand the Linux file structure here. Your users files will be found at /home/username/. Substitute the name you use for your user instead of /username/ There will also be a directory at /home/username/Desktop amongst others and a number of hidden directories and files containing configuration data. If you try to do what you are asking to do the outcome for your configuration is uncertain.

Comment: @PonJar sorry I just corrected. I want to mount it on /home/naufil/Desktop

Comment: This sounds strange, why would one want do do that?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205841/how-do-i-mount-a-folder-from-another-partition) gives you the principles to follow if you want to try to do this. I suggest you don’t try to mount your home drive but symlink it instead.

Backup your system. This could go wrong.

I think you need to work in a live environment. (Using install media and choose “Try Ubuntu”)

You will need to make the following directories on the system partition:

1. /home
2. /home/naufil
3. /home/naufil/Desktop

You will need to copy the hidden directories and files from your home partition to /home/naufil

You will need to edit your /etc/fstab file so that the home partition mounts at somewhere like /mnt/home

You will need to place a symlink in /home/naufil/Desktop that points to /mnt/home/home/naufil

I cannot guarantee that this will work as expected or that it will achieve what you are looking for since it’s a rather odd thing to want to do.

Comment: I want to use my HDD for storing data and not programs. Because ubuntu also stores programs in /home other than /bin. Saving programs in /home will reduce the efficiency and will miss the point of having SSD. Therefore I am trying to isolate HDD from installed programs

Comment: In my experience programs are not installed under /home. Which programs have done that for you? Perhaps a better question would be how to stop it happening and how to move or reinstall to the SSD

Comment: yes you are right. Should I again post the question? Or can you answer it here please

Comment: I recently installed anaconda and it was saved in home

Comment: I keep /home inside / (root), but have all my data in a data partition. I used to have data on HDD, but with larger SSD now have most used data on SSD, but separate /mnt/data partition and links into /home for folders and only with some data & backups on HDD. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: The anaconda installation instructions say the default install location is within /home. They recommend the default, specify you shouldn’t use /usr but don’t prevent changing the install location. I guess you have two choices. Leave it as it is and see if you find it slow. Alternatively uninstall and reinstall at a location on the SSD. I’d guess you will find the HDD fine and the SSD not noticeably faster for this application, but that is only a guess. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/