# '.lnk' shown in a mounted folder

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I'm trying to mount a Windows partition in my Ubuntu system so I edited fstab with this:

```
/dev/sda4   /mnt/windows    ntfs    rw,auto     0   0
```

This mounts without any problem my Windows partition into /mnt/windows but when I try to access to an especific folder I find this with ls -l:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 2 root root        844 oct  6 17:21 'Universidad - Acceso directo.lnk'
```

and I cannot access using cd.

I tried using lnkinfo to see if it was usefull to me but it wasn't.

```
Windows Shortcut information:
Contains a link target identifier


Link information:

Creation time           : Sep 12, 2018 11:54:32.625892600 UTC
Modification time       : Sep 29, 2020 15:12:40.035328300 UTC
Access time         : Sep 29, 2020 15:12:40.035328300 UTC
File size           : 4096 bytes
Icon index          : 0
Show Window value       : 0x00001000
Hot Key value           : 4096
File attribute flags        : 0x00000010
    Is directory (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
Drive type          : Fixed (3)
Drive serial number     : 0xb65790ec
Volume label            : FREEDOS
Local path          : D:\Escritorio\Universidad

Link target identifier:
Shell item list
    Number of items     : 3

Shell item: 1
    Item type       : Root folder
    Class type indicator    : 0x1f (Root folder)
    Shell folder identifier : 20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d
    Shell folder name   : My Computer

Shell item: 2
    Item type       : Volume
    Class type indicator    : 0x2e (Volume)
Extension block: 1
    Signature       : 0xbeef0026

Shell item: 3
    Item type       : File entry
    Class type indicator    : 0x31 (File entry: Directory)
    Name            : UNIVER~1
    Modification time   : Sep 29, 2020 15:12:42
    File attribute flags    : 0x00000010
        Is directory (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
Extension block: 1
    Signature       : 0xbeef0004 (File entry extension)
    Long name       : Universidad
    Creation time       : Sep 12, 2018 11:54:34
    Access time     : Sep 29, 2020 15:12:42
    NTFS file reference : MFT entry: 45880, sequence: 1
```

How can I fix it and access to the folder?
In Windows the folder it's not a direct access.

[Folder shown in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB2MH.jpg)

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and mounting Windows 10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The file 'Universidad - Acceso directo.lnk' is a windows shortcut file. It therefore will work only as expected from within the Windows operating system.

Linux **symbolic links** provide similar functionality. Since the windows file system `ntfs` [appears to support them to some extent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301797/how-to-disable-hide-completely-power-off-button-from-ubuntu-20-04), you could create a symbolic link and use that for navigation.

A somewhat more complicated approach is to create a folder in the folder where the windows shortcut resides, and then [**`mount --bind`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205841/how-do-i-mount-a-folder-from-another-partition/205847#205847) your target folder to that folder. Next to being more complicated, it will work in Linux only.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Finally I fixed it... My laptop has 2 hard drives (HDD and SSD), Windows and Linux are installed in the SSD but I configured Windows desktop in the HDD so Desktop is in D:\Desktop not in C:\Desktop.
D is /dev/sdb1
C is /dev/sda4

I was trying to mount C and thats why all the folders located there were shown as symbolic links.