# How to disable/hide completely Power Off button from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I want to hide completely or disable the function of Power Off from the gnome panel or it's menu.
I just need a way to prevent me from shuting down unless I use

```
sudo poweroff 
sudo reboot
```

Comment: There is a gnome shell extension called BringOutSubmenu did you try that one? It has dconf setting to remove Poweroff button from menu. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/

Comment: I installed it now, it just brought out the Power Off button. The question it is how to disable/hide completely the Power Off button.

Comment: Ok open the extension folder and you will find compile-schemas-script.. Run it and then refresh gnome shell.. Then find the key 'brngout' in dconf editor

Comment: Yes UnKNOWn, that worked like a charm and finally all buttons are removed.

Comment: Great to know.. Thanks!!!