# Install Ubuntu for large applications (SSD+HDD setup)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, matlab

I have a Dell G5 notebook with two drives (256Gb SSD and 1Tb HDD).
I use it only for Ubuntu 20.04 (no dual-boot) and intend to keep it that way.
For the first installation, I was using the system entirely on the SSD and leaving the HDD only for data.
However, I do need to use very demanding and space consuming applications such as Matlab and Xilinx Vivado, and I ran out of space very fast. However, they both use many system libraries, so I could not just install them in the HDD.
So... I will need to do a new Ubuntu installation in such a way that I can profit a little more from the HDD space for this large apps.
Since I am a newbie, I am asking for a little more insight of how should this be done and how should I build my system partitions so I don't need to do a fresh install again in the next few months

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `df -h` show? How large does / need to be. I like to keep /home inside / as the hidden user files are small. My / with /home is 8.4GB, but all data is in data partition(s). I used to have all my data on HDD with / on SSD. But newer larger SSD allows almost all my data on SSD, and HDD is now mostly for backup. If newer user, having / on SSD and /home on HDD is easiest as that sets mount, fstab entry & ownership & permissions. If you add data partitions, you have to do all that yourself Not really difficult but requires some terminal work.

Comment: My / directory is currently using 52G and my /home is 140G (from 234G available in the partition). However, I still have to install Vivado (a proprietary app from Xilinx for FPGA programming) which requires another 65Gb. Since this Ubuntu installation is only 2 months old, and I will probably have to install some more stuff in the near future, I think this install is not sustainable in the long term and I want to correct while a re-install is still not so painful

Comment: I consider myself a newbie Linux user (I don't fully understand its directories hierarchy, for instance) but I have no problem in using the terminal if someone provides me appropriate instructions to do so. Maybe I can manage to do the manual partitioning if you could kindly instruct me or provide a link with the step by step

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit and update your question with all the new informaiton](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1310240/edit).

Comment: This is what I do. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198 &
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1901437 Start simple with just one partition, I do not yet have fully partitioned either my SSD nor my HDD. Create partition & format ext4. Create mount point & add to fstab to auto mount on reboot. Then add folder & link it. If that works you can link many folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend to reinstall the OS, you could create a separate partition on the HDD, dedicated for any system directory, let's say `/usr` (where the most libraries are) and mount it at its place. As I remember correctly you can do that via the installation dialogue.

You can achieve the same result without reinstalling the OS. Just use `gparted` in order to resize the existing partitions on the HDD and create a new one, then follow the accepted answer of this question: [How to move /usr to a new partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/656/566421)

Another way is to move the `/usr` directory into the HDD and then mount it by using the bind option of the mount command in order to mount it at its place - the steps are described here: [How do I mount a folder from another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205841/how-do-i-mount-a-folder-from-another-partition)