# How to define the fstab entry for /dirname when /home is already defined

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

I refer to the post [How do I mount a folder from another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205841/how-do-i-mount-a-folder-from-another-partition).  I have /home associated with a partition and this is working.

From the post it seems that my fstab should read:

```
/whatever    /home    none    bind
```

Can I have /whatever related to this partition **without** is being under /home?  In scripts I would like to refer to this location as `/whatever` rather than as `/home/whatever`

I come from the Windows environment the my reasoning is that Drive D could have any number of folders under it.

Thanks

---

Clarification note

I have the following in my fstab

UUID=109bff64-xxxx /home           ext4    defaults          0       2

I want to add a directory **/whatever** to resolve to the save device having UUID=109bff64-xxxx.

I do not want **/whatever** to be under **/home**.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what the end result you want looks like. I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Bind mounts essentially give you two locations where the same data are located. Is that what you want? What is `/whatever`? What do you want it to be? Where do you want to have its data mounted?

Comment: @terdon. Clarification added. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So why do you need a bind mount for this? Wouldn't a simple symlink be enough? Something like `sudo ln -s /home /whatever`? And your comment about "drive D having multiple folders" is also confusing, `/home` can have as many folders under it as you like. I am having trouble understanding what advantage you see in having this `/whatever`. Why is it easier to use `/whatever` in a script than to use `/home`? I feel this may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).

Comment: I don't have an opinion on symbolic links.  I come from Windows and I find it challenging to wrap my mind around going from devices that have names (A:, B:, ...) to a devices that  are essentially folders.  With Windows, C: drive has folders underneath it; here I am saying that /whatever point to ANOTHER folder /home. I can't (my ignorance) appreciate why /dev/sdaX is not the reference point for all folders under it.

Maybe it needs time to sink in.

Comment: There isn't much difference, really. "C" is also a directory, and you can think of it as such. Presumably, Windows also does some sort of mapping between the directory `\C:` and the drive. So just like your system partition is accessible via `\C:` in Windows, so your home partition is accessible via `/home` in Linux. Sure, the mechanics might be different, but from the user perspective it is basically the same. But, again, what is the benefit for you in having `/whatever` point to `/home`? What can you do with `/whatever` that you cannot do with `/home`?

Comment: I came tot he same conclusion. In fact I didn't create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do this with a bind mount, that seems like overkill. If all you want is to access the data in `/home` from the directory `/whatever`, a symlink is enough:

```
sudo ln -s /home /whatever
```

That will create the symlink `/whatever` and you can use it just as you would `/home`.

I don't see any advantage to using a bind mount instead if all you want is a different entry point to `/home`. But then I also don't really understand why you would prefer to use `/whatever` instead of `/home`. They are both top level directories under `/` so there seems to be no benefit in using one over the other.

In any case, if you insist on using a bind mount, then you would first need to create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir /whatever
```

And then add this line to the end of your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/home    /whatever   bind  defaults
```

That means "bind mount `/home` to `/whatever`".

Comment: Before following this read @terdon's comments under the question.