# Developing application with expanded Filesystem (Still getting no space left on device error)

Tags: 18.04, mount, sd-card, storage

After mounting a 64Gb sdcard (/dev/mmcblk1p1) to my embedded device that has topped out of its 16Gb emmc (/dev/mmcblk0p1) `df -h` returns the following which looks correct:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1   14G   13G  509M  97% /
none            3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G   30M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk1p1   58G   52M   55G   1% /mnt/sdcard
tmpfs           778M   12K  778M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           778M     0  778M   0% /run/user/1000
```

However, now when I attempt to clone mediapipe I get the following out of space error:

```
fatal: write error: No space left on device70 MiB | 12.58 MiB/s
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I assume this is a high level question and I am not sure how to ask it, but how can I "link" additional storage from my sd into the application development space? I have things that I need for the application in `/` so sd cant be fully independent. Would it just be easier to boot off the sdcard from the get go so that additional storage is there from the beginning?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you elaborate on what you mean by “SD can’t be fully independent”? Also, will the SD card always be present for the device, or do you hope to hot swap?

Comment: Thanks, I'm excited to be part of the community! We do not need to hot swap, itll always be there. By independent I mean I have dependencies on root (in the emmc) that I still need to use. E.g. python and opencv are in the emmc that I need for my application

Comment: If the SD card will be persistent, you could [use a symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/a/205847/1222991) to have certain directories read and write from the card. Another option would be to  [mount the SD card to a specific directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/154185/1222991) that will be used by the application. If the SD card will only be used by the application, then the second option may the one to go with.

Comment: thx for your response @matigo. I have already successfully mounted the sd using /etc/fstab, so I guess this is more so a question on how to deal with the additional disk during application development. I am assuming since I am out of space in `/` all my development needs to be done where there is storage remaining ( in my case `/mnt/sdcard` ), but do you see any problems arising because alot of my dependencies remain in `/`

Comment: Change your mount point. Rather than `/mnt/sdcard`, use your program’s main data directory. You’re not limited to locations in `/mnt`.